# FeetInches Program/overloading/modify operators

Tags: c++, testing, overloading

The prompt i use i get from my friend's class. here is the prompt. I need to create a FeetInches class and modify it using relational overloading operators. I have got both the .cpp and .h files working. I just need to create another .cpp file that tests the program. here is the question for each part. please let me know if i have done everything correctly. the second .cpp file needs to be labeled as lab feetinches. it must also call/test every "member function".

feetinches.h

```
// Specification file for the FeetInches class
#ifndef FEETINCHES_H
#define FEETINCHES_H

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class FeetInches;   // Forward Declaration

// Function Prototypes for Overloaded Stream Operators
ostream &operator << (ostream &, const FeetInches &);
istream &operator >> (istream &, FeetInches &);

// The FeetInches class holds distances or measurements 
// expressed in feet and inches.

class FeetInches
{
private:
int feet;        // To hold a number of feet
int inches;      // To hold a number of inches
void simplify(); // Defined in FeetInches.cpp
public:
// Constructor
FeetInches(int f = 0, int i = 0)
{
    feet = f;
    inches = i;
    simplify();
}

// Mutator functions
void setFeet(int f)
{
    feet = f;
}

void setInches(int i)
{
    inches = i;
    simplify();
}

// Accessor functions
int getFeet() const
{
    return feet;
}

int getInches() const
{
    return inches;
}

// Overloaded operator functions
FeetInches operator + (const FeetInches &); // Overloaded +
bool operator <= (const FeetInches &);
bool operator >= (const FeetInches &);
bool operator != (const FeetInches &);
FeetInches operator - (const FeetInches &); // Overloaded -
FeetInches operator ++ ();                  // Prefix ++
FeetInches operator ++ (int);               // Postfix ++
bool operator > (const FeetInches &);       // Overloaded >
bool operator < (const FeetInches &);       // Overloaded <
bool operator == (const FeetInches &);      // Overloaded ==

// copy constructor
FeetInches (FeetInches &right)
{
    feet = right.feet;
    inches = right.inches;
}

//multiply function 
FeetInches multiply(FeetInches obj)
{
    FeetInches temp;
    temp.feet = feet * obj.feet;
    temp.inches = inches * obj.inches;
    temp.simplify();
    return temp;
}

                                            // Conversion functions
operator double();
operator int();

// Friends
friend ostream &operator << (ostream &, const FeetInches &);
friend istream &operator >> (istream &, FeetInches &);
};

#endif#pragma once
```

feetinches.cpp

```
// Implementation file for the FeetInches class
#include <cstdlib>  // Needed for abs()
#include "kenny_feetInches.h"

//************************************************************
// Definition of member function simplify. This function     *
// checks for values in the inches member greater than       *
// twelve or less than zero. If such a value is found,       *
// the numbers in feet and inches are adjusted to conform    *
// to a standard feet & inches expression. For example,      *
// 3 feet 14 inches would be adjusted to 4 feet 2 inches and *
// 5 feet -2 inches would be adjusted to 4 feet 10 inches.   *
//************************************************************

void FeetInches::simplify()
{
if (inches >= 12)
{
    feet += (inches / 12);
    inches = inches % 12;
}
else if (inches < 0)
{
    feet -= ((abs(inches) / 12) + 1);
    inches = 12 - (abs(inches) % 12);
}
}

//**********************************************
// Overloaded binary + operator.               *
//**********************************************

FeetInches FeetInches::operator + (const FeetInches &right)
{
FeetInches temp;

temp.inches = inches + right.inches;
temp.feet = feet + right.feet;
temp.simplify();
return temp;
}


//**********************************************
// Overloaded binary - operator.               *
//**********************************************

FeetInches FeetInches::operator - (const FeetInches &right)
{
FeetInches temp;

temp.inches = inches - right.inches;
temp.feet = feet - right.feet;
temp.simplify();
return temp;
}



//*************************************************************
// Overloaded prefix ++ operator. Causes the inches member to *
// be incremented. Returns the incremented object.            *
//*************************************************************

FeetInches FeetInches::operator ++ ()
{
++inches;
simplify();
return *this;
}

//***************************************************************
// Overloaded postfix ++ operator. Causes the inches member to  *
// be incremented. Returns the value of the object before the   *
// increment.                                                   *
//***************************************************************

FeetInches FeetInches::operator ++ (int)
{
FeetInches temp(feet, inches);

inches++;
simplify();
return temp;
}

//************************************************************
// Overloaded > operator. Returns true if the current object *
// is set to a value greater than that of right.             *
//************************************************************

bool FeetInches::operator > (const FeetInches &right)
{
bool status;

if (feet > right.feet)
    status = true;
else if (feet == right.feet && inches > right.inches)
    status = true;
else
    status = false;

return status;
}

//**********************************************
// Overloaded the <= operator.               *
//**********************************************

bool FeetInches::operator <= (const FeetInches &right)
{
bool status;

    if (feet <= right.feet)
        status = true;
    else if (feet == right.feet && inches <= right.inches)
        status = true;
    else
        status = false;
    return status;
 }

//**********************************************
// Overloaded the >= operator.               *
//**********************************************

bool FeetInches::operator >= (const FeetInches &right)
{
bool status;

if (feet <= right.feet)
    status = true;
else if (feet == right.feet && inches >= right.inches)
    status = true;
else
    status = false;
return status;
}

//**********************************************
// Overloaded the != operator.               *
//**********************************************

bool FeetInches::operator != (const FeetInches &right)
{
bool status;

if (feet <= right.feet)
    status = true;
else if (feet == right.feet && inches != right.inches)
    status = true;
else
    status = false;
return status;
}




//************************************************************
// Overloaded < operator. Returns true if the current object *
// is set to a value less than that of right.                * 
//************************************************************

bool FeetInches::operator < (const FeetInches &right)
{
bool status;

if (feet < right.feet)
    status = true;
else if (feet == right.feet && inches < right.inches)
    status = true;
else
    status = false;

return status;
}

//*************************************************************
// Overloaded == operator. Returns true if the current object *
// is set to a value equal to that of right.                  *
//*************************************************************

bool FeetInches::operator == (const FeetInches &right)
{
bool status;

if (feet == right.feet && inches == right.inches)
    status = true;
else
    status = false;

return status;
}

//********************************************************
// Overloaded << operator. Gives cout the ability to     *
// directly display FeetInches objects.                  *
//* *******************************************************

ostream &operator<<(ostream &strm, const FeetInches &obj)
{
strm << obj.feet << " feet, " << obj.inches << " inches";
return strm;
}

//********************************************************
// Overloaded >> operator. Gives cin the ability to      *
// store user input directly into FeetInches objects.    *
//********************************************************   

istream &operator >> (istream &strm, FeetInches &obj)
{
// Prompt the user for the feet.
cout << "Feet: ";
strm >> obj.feet;

// Prompt the user for the inches.
cout << "Inches: ";
strm >> obj.inches;

// Normalize the values.
obj.simplify();

return strm;
}

//*************************************************************
// Conversion function to convert a FeetInches object         *
// to a double.                                               *
//*************************************************************

FeetInches::operator double()
{
double temp = feet;

temp += (inches / 12.0);
return temp;
} 

//*************************************************************
// Conversion function to convert a FeetInches object         *
// to an int.                                                 *
//*************************************************************

FeetInches:: operator int()
{
return feet;
}
```

Any help will be much appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: If this is **working** code and you want it to be reviewed then you should check out [CodeReview.SE](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: only the two files is working code. i still need the second .cpp done to test the two files. to see if they are working or not.

Comment: Gotta watch that word, "working." Code doesn't work until it's been tested (and sometimes not even then, but let's assume the testing is complete and successful), which is what you're currently trying to do. Testing is a really broad topic, but first, are you having trouble building a program with two cpp files or are you unsure what to put in the second file?

Comment: unsure of what to put in the second file. im new to programming. and am trying to teach myself how to. but this is the first program i have run into where i have no idea how to use a new .cpp to test the current work i have already done. lol.

Comment: the second .cpp only needs to be created to test the other .cpp and .h files.

Comment: The basic is `#include "feetinches.h" int main() { /* tests go here */ }`. where "tests go here" calls all of your functions with known inputs and compares the results against the expected output. For each function you will likely have multiple tests with the input of each call crafted to test a path through the function. All of the paths should be tested. All of the boundary conditions should be tested as well. Beyond that the question becomes too broad for SO and personal research is required. Wikipedia doesn't look like a bad start: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_testing